# Stacked bar plot by wordcount and

Tags: r, bar-chart

I'm trying to create a stacked box plot based on the word count depending on the variable "party".

The data looks like this:

[image: Data]

Thats the code I use:

```
library('tidyverse')
x_words_counted %>% 
      slice(1:100) %>% 
      ggplot(aes(x = reorder(word,-n), y = n, fill = partei)) + 
      geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "stack") + 
      theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 60, hjust = 1)) + 
      xlab("")
```

On ggplot the number of words is shown summed up, but not in a decreasing order based on the total number of words after summing up by party (or not if only one party is using the word).

[image: Pic2]

Comment: Try `reorder(word,-n, sum)`. By default reorder uses the mean.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by **@stefan** (Many thanks and all credit to him), changing the default aggregation function in `reorder()` could alleviate the issue. And please next time include a sample of data using `dput()`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
#Data
df <- data.frame(partei=c('linke','afd','afd','grune',
                          'spd','spd','cdu','grune','cdu',
                          'spd','linke','linke'),
                 word=c('menschen','bundestag','deutschland',
                        'bundestag','bundestag','menschen',
                        'deutschland','menschen','bundestag',
                        'danke','bundestag','bundesregierung'),
                 n=c(7611,7561,7312,7054,6699,6469,6338,6201,6194,6037,6007,5853))
#Plot
df %>% 
  slice(1:100) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = reorder(word,-n,sum), y = n, fill = partei)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "stack") + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 60, hjust = 1)) + 
  xlab("")
```

Output:

[image]